# Infrastructure environment for running Nuxt 3

Tags: nuxtjs3

I'm thinking about Nuxt 3 infrastructure environment. If you could give me some advice I would appreciate it.

I'm thinking of running Nuxt 3 on AWS ECS or Serverless (e.g. AWS Lambda). My application is a membership site that requires login functionality, etc. and uses an API managed by a separate project to retrieve/update data. Some of the content will be static, but most of the data needs to be displayed in real time. For this reason, SSR will be used.Therefore, a server is required to run it.

In the case of ECS, it is easier to adjust the Node version because it uses Docker. And we can easily handle the load of the site by increasing the number of tasks in ECS.

On the other hand, I think there is an option to deploy to a serverless environment such as Lambda. In the case of serverless, I think there is an advantage to reduce operational costs because there is no need to manage servers with the recognition that Nitro can be used. However, I think there is a disadvantage of not being able to specify the Node version in detail and handle large response sizes.

If there is a de facto standard infrastructure environment I would like to know.